# YOLO v8 automatic augmentation in the fly

Tags: linux, yolo, yolov8, image-augmentation

i cant find correct information in the internet. I 'd like to know if Yolo v8 automaticy augments training set and how can i menage this process.

Can i somehow see how much there is newly created images(durging augmentation) and see the preview of some samples

I cant find any tutorial